# How to remove backslash from url when returning from c# code?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, web-services, svc

```
    public Uri GetCrmUrl(string phone,string organisationid,string server)
    {
        string _URL = string.Empty;
        string clienturl = @"https://petsolutions.crm8.dynamics.com/nga/engagementhub.aspx?org="+organisationid+"&server="+server;
        Uri x = new Uri(clienturl,UriKind.Absolute);
        return x;
    }
```

I am trying to returning this url directly on html .
But the value returning is like:

```
https:\/\/petsolutions.crm8.dynamics.com\/nga\/engagementhub.aspx?org=dkejverv&server=dfvfevf
```

while the expected output is:

```
https://petsolutions.crm8.dynamics.com/nga/engagementhub.aspx?org=dkejverv&server=dfvfevf
```

How can i remove those slashes from my URL ?

In C# code, code is returning correct values but at the time of HTML Rendering there are some backslashes there. [Check Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmOgs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the String.Replace() method:

```
string test = clienturl.Replace(@"\", string.empty);
Uri x = new Uri(test ,UriKind.Absolute);
    return x;
```

Comment: String.Replace is working fine in c#code. Problem is occurring at the time of returning value in HTML

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are looking for your string but this example works just the way you want:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri test = GetCrmUrl("00000", "orgid", "server");

            Console.WriteLine(test);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static Uri GetCrmUrl(string phone, string organisationid, string server)
        {
            string clienturl = @"https://petsolutions.crm8.dynamics.com/nga/engagementhub.aspx?org=" + organisationid + "&server=" + server;
            Uri x = new Uri(clienturl, UriKind.Absolute);
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Returns:

https://petsolutions.crm8.dynamics.com/nga/engagementhub.aspx?org=orgid&server=server

No need to remove slashes at all.

Comment: Hi, Your code is exactly returning what i want. But if we return this to a webpage , then the same slash problem is occurring. 
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  return new Uri(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(clienturl).ToString());
```